# Como trabajar con LINQ en un controlador NET CORE 3.1

Tags: net

Estoy trabajando en net core 3.1 con una base de datos, y quiero obtener los productos pero con su respectiva categoria subcategoria y marca, en la base de datos solo tengo los id obviamente, es decir en la tabla articulos tengo idcategoria idsubcategoria e idmarca.

Tengo lo siguiente:
Interfaz IproductoService:

```
using APIGESTION.model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APIGESTION.Services
{
    public interface IProductoService
    {
        public void Add(ProductoRequest model)
        {

        }
        List<Producto> GetProductos();
    }
}
```

Y su implementacion con LINQ:

```
using APIGESTION.model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace APIGESTION.Services
{
    public class ProductoService : IProductoService
    {
        public void Add(ProductoRequest model)
        {

            using (gestionContext db = new gestionContext())
            {
                using (var transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
                    try
                    {

                        var producto = new Producto();

                        producto.IdProducto = model.IdProducto;
                        producto.Precio = model.Precio;
                        producto.Stock = model.Stock;
                        producto.IdCategoria = model.idCategoria;
                        producto.nombreCategoria = model.nombreCategoria;
                        producto.idSubCategoria = model.idSubCategoria;
                        producto.nombreSubCategoria = model.nombreSubCategoria;
                        producto.idMarca = model.idMarca;
                        producto.nombreMarca = model.nombreMarca;
                        producto.CodAlfanumerico = model.CodAlfanumerico;
                        producto.CodBarra = model.CodBarra;
                        producto.Aliiva = model.Aliiva;
                        producto.Unidad = model.Unidad;
                        producto.Contenido = model.Contenido;
                        producto.costo = model.costo;
                      
                        db.Productos.Add(producto);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                   
                        transaction.Commit();

                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw new Exception("Ocurrio un error en la insercion");
                    }
            }

        }

        public List<Producto> GetProductos()
        {
            using (gestionContext db = new gestionContext())
            {
              var productos=(from p in db.Productos join cat in db.Categoria on p.idCategoria equals cat.IdCategoria join
                subcat in db.Subcategoria on p.idSubCategoria equals subcat.IdSubcategoria join m in db.Marcas on
                p.idMarca equals m.IdMarca
                select new
                {
                    IdProducto = p.IdProducto,
                    Precio = p.Precio,
                    Stock = p.Stock,
                    IdCategoria = p.idCategoria,
                    IdSubcategoria = p.idSubCategoria,
                    IdMarca = p.idMarca,
                    CodAlfanumerico = p.CodAlfanumerico,
                    CodBarra = p.CodBarra,
                    Aliiva = p.Aliiva,
                    Unidad = p.Unidad,
                    Contenido = p.Contenido,
                    costo = p.costo,
                    NombreProducto = p.NombreProducto,
                    nombreCategoria = p.nombreCategoria,
                    nombreMarca = p.nombreMarca,
                });
                return (List<Producto>)productos;
            }

         
           
       
           
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora bien como llamo en el controlador de articulos o productos al metodo que obtiene el listado?

```
namespace APIGESTION.Controllers
{


    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class ProductoController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly gestionContext _context;
        private IProductoService _producto;
        public ProductoController(gestionContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Cliente

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetProducto()
        {
           var Producto = _producto.GetProductos();
            return Producto;
        }
..demas codigo
```

No se si esta bien asi. No da error de compilacion pero cuando voy a mi aplicacion cliente y solicito los datos me dice:

**System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
_producto fue null.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando inyeccion de dependencias, pero no le estas pasando a tu controlador la dependencia, por lo tanto, _producto es nulo.

Te esta faltando en el constructor agregar la misma, asi como agregaste el contexto:

```
public ProductoController(
    gestionContext context,
    IProductoService producto
    )
{
    _context = context;
    _producto = producto;
}
```

Comment: Ok muchas gracias